# How to measure toilet flush valve?

Tags: toilet

I plan to replace my toilet flush tank with hydroflush. The requirement says that I need to have a 2" toilet flush valve. What does this part look like and how do I go about measuring it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image attached to [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/24383/33), shows what the flush valve is.

[image: Toilet Tank Guts]

It typically includes the overflow tube, but more specifically it's the flapper (or a device that controls the flow of water into the bowl).

Measure the tank discharge (flush) tube (the hole the flush valve (flapper) covers), to determine the size flush valve you need. The hole might be slightly larger or smaller then 2", but close enough is close enough.