# Is this how the adjustment on a toilet flapper works?

Tags: toilet

Some styles of toilet flappers have an adjustable ring. The ring closes completely, partially, or fully opens the airflow into the hollow center.

[image: toilet flapper]

I'd like to confirm how it works. It is meant to adjust the time it takes for water to fill its interior.

If it is fully open, water quickly fills inside the flapper, and it quickly sinks, shutting down the water draining from the tank to the toilet bowl.

If it is partially open, the water takes longer, and more water is flushed.

If it is fully closed, the water still makes it inside, eventually making it sink. The water still makes it inside because the closure is not watertight, and so the water takes slightly longer to be inside.

This is my understanding. Is this how the adjustment on a toilet floater works?

I'm asking because even when the flapper's ring is fully in the sealed position (little air/water can go in/out), the lever still must be held to get a reasonable flush. Otherwise the flapper simply sinks. The objective from the question is to figure out what I misunderstand, so that I can solve this problem.

I'm having this issue with two new floaters, one generic, and one apparently specific to the particular brand (American Standard). In other words, this is not an issue of a
[slow leak](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/14268/115116).

Comment: just follow the manufacturer's adjustment instructions

Comment: Your definition of "reasonable" is likely not the same as that of the jokers whose job it is to come up with "water saving" devices to meet arbitrary government regulations. We all know about those "water saving" toilets that actually increase water use because they must be flushed multiple times.